# Why Qt QWebEngineView working not proper way?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, webengine

Trying to get work properly `QWebEngineView` widget.
Need to display webpage in kinda embedded browser in my app.

From the beginning everything works fine.
I test view with `google.com` url.
Widget shows page, I can input, click on buttons for search, etc.
But after some time widget seems to crash.
It shows empty window instead of web page.

I've got such log output:

> [9428:10292:1007/160758.387:ERROR:sync_point_manager.cc(249)] Client waiting on non-existent sync token
>   The thread 0x13f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

What can I do to fix this?

I use **Qt 5.13.1** version and **Visual Studio 2019**.

Here is the source code:

```
webView = new QWebEngineView(this);
webView->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, 200), QSize(this->width(), this->height() - 200)));
webView->load(QUrl("http://google.com/"));
webView->setFocus();
webView->show();
```

Comment: @eyllanesc i've add below